# Maxima encountered a Lisp error: I do not understand what the problem is

Tags: draw, maxima, draw2d, wxmaxima

I am trying to do an example in wxmaxima

```
  wxplot_size:[1024,768]$
wxanimate_framerate:2$
with_slider_draw(
   /* The parameter we want to assign to the slider and all values it can assume */
   R,Resistors,

   /* The thing we actually want to draw */
   key=concat("R=",float(R)," Ohm"),
   explicit(
    ev(Voltage(R,t)),
       t,0,20
   ),line_type=dots,color=black,
   key=concat("R=0.0 Ohm"),
   explicit(
       ev(Voltage(0,t)),
       t,0,20
   ),
   yrange=[-1,1],
   grid=true
)$
```

and I get the following error. Can anybody help me?

```
Maxima encountered a Lisp error:
 Condition in CDR [or a callee]: INTERNAL-SIMPLE-TYPE-ERROR: |$Resistors| is not of type LIST: 
Automatically continuing.
To enable the Lisp debugger set *debugger-hook* to nil.
```

Sorry, but I couldn't put it as code
Thanks

Comment: The documentation I found (http://arcoramexico.net/wxmaxima-16.12.2/info/wxmaxima.html) says that the second argument must be a list, namely the list of values which `R` will take on. If `Resistors` is not a list, I guess it should be.

Comment: --> Resistors:makelist(i/20,i,0,20);
(Resistors) [0,1/20,1/10,3/20,1/5,1/4,3/10,7/20,2/5,9/20,1/2,11/20,3/5,13/20,7/10,3/4,4/5,17/20,9/10,19/20,1]
the list is created before